# Trying to get non object error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, object

On the page with id 239 I am trying to hide a certain post-format from displaying on it, however I am getting this error on all pages:

"Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php on line 4337"

This is the code I am using in the functions.php file:

```
function exclude_campaigns( $query ) {
     if( $query->is_main_query() && $query is_page(239) ) {
        $tax_query = array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_campaigns' );
```

Comment: You should get rid of `$query` in `$query is_page(239)`.

Comment: Its still giving the same error

Comment: You should get rid of `$query` before `is_main_query()` as well.

Comment: Cheers for the reply I tried that but it doesnt work either :(

A different errors appears: "Notice: is_main_query was called incorrectly. In pre_get_posts" With the same non object erorr underneath

Answer (score 0):

After removing the `$query` before the is_page check, it works on my example :(

Anyway, the error indicates some problem with the `is_page()` function. You could try to replace that check:

```
if( $query->is_main_query() && ! empty( $query->posts ) && $query->posts[0]->ID == 239 ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah! That stops the error from showing but then it doesnt hide the post-format. Shouldn't $query->posts be $query->page? To find the page with id 239?

Comment: No it should not. `page` is just a type of post. To troubleshoot the problem, I suggest doing a `var_dump` of the `$query` object to verify you got the field values right in your replacement of `tax_query`.

Comment: Thinking on it some more, are you really using post formats as properties of that particular page? Or are you showing your posts in a custom query on that page?

Comment: Im using "wordpress ajax load more" to display the posts on the page, but the odd thing is if i remove the if statement: if( $query->is_main_query() &&... etc it correctly hides that post-format from the page but it also hides it in the CMS posts page

Comment: Perhaps it's not considered the main query then :) If you're loading via ajax, you could try checking for the `DOING_AJAX` constant.